# Error from SQL Server when run app without admin privileges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi

I have an app written in Delphi (it is not my app). When it starts, it is connecting to SQL Server instance (for example on localhost). If I run app with admin privileges everything is ok, but if I run it without - there is an error: `SQL Server Connection Terminated`.
App uses one dll file.

How can I figure out what is wrong or what needs admin privileges?

Comment: Are there any configuration files or ini files that are accesed by this application ? If so, than make sure the application is not installed somewhere in the "program files" directory, since windows 7 and up does not like that and wants admin privileges to do that

Comment: Unfortunately they are. I made new user (not administrator) and I logged into him. Then I tried to see difference in app operation when I start app without privileges. I'm doing this because I want to do portable version of this app.

Comment: you have 2 options : 1 contact the author and hit him with a baseball bat until he corrects his stupid mistake and puts all config files where they belong, 2. always install in other folder than "program files" folder

Comment: If you want a portable application than Delphi is indeed the best choice, but the author made a big mistake with his config files

Comment: You made me laugh the first option :D So I will check this second at first. Can you tell me what exactly do you mean by "puts all config files where they belong"? Because I'm not sure if I understand it right.

Comment: In the old days software used to keep its config files in the same folder as the executable file. Since windows 7 this is not recommended anymore, and software should store config files and log files and stuff like that in the users AppData directory. If the application is to be used by anyone using this computer it should be in the "all users" appdata directory

Comment: Nice to know about it. I will check what I can do with this. I would be very glad if it could help.

Comment: There is not much you can do about it, this has to be done by the programmer of the application. That is why installing in another directory than "progarm files" will help because than the application does not require admin privileges to acces these files

Comment: Our software (multiple EXE's and DLL's) connects to SQL Server as well, and has been for almost 20 years. Never such an issue. What's different about yours than ours?

Comment: @GuidoG I wouldn't say "not recommended". It's just simply and purely "not allowed". The only cases where it works are breaking the rules. AV's should put them in software jail. It's like storing gasoline in your bedroom.

Comment: Try Sysinternals' Process Monitor to see what fails when running under a restricted account.

Comment: @JerryDodge Its not allowed but can be done easy. Thats why i wrote not recommended. Anyway, I wanted to know if the software tried to read and write a config file from the programs folder. If so than here is where the error occurs, the application will fail to read its connection string and thus also cannot connect to sql server

Comment: @GuidoG It's also not allowed to steal a bottle of wine from the liquor store. But I still can if I wanted to. Does that mean it's just not recommended? :-)

Comment: @JerryDodge Are we really goning to discus this ?

Comment: You are being hit by folder virtualization, the application will read it's configuration file under %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\<rest of the path>. Check if the config file is correct under that location.

Comment: @whosrdaddy That is exactly what I was trying to explain here. The application probably is badly written and reads/writes its config files in its install dir. I have seen cases where the folder virtualization reads files from there but writes into the virtualstore path.

Comment: @GuidoG, yes I know, just trying to make it more concrete for the OP ;)